# HMT or HABTM for Orders and Items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Fairly new to rails and trying to understand which relationships to use before going forward.

I have two models: `orders` and `items`. This is a many to many relationship, but I'm unsure of which relationship to use.

Orders might have delivery time, quantity of items, etc.

Lastly, what would you call the model joining `orders` and `items` if using HMT?

Comment: Do you need to be able to go backwards:  Given an Item, what orders does it appear on?  If so, it's the classic case of HABTM, and there's a perfect example here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: And the default join table would be named items_orders (alphabetical order)

Comment: Which one to use?  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: @Daiku sorry on mobile device acc - I don't need to go backwards given an item. Only need to see which items an order has. Should I use HMT? What would you call the model if I use HMT?

Comment: As the last link says - it depends on if the join table will have anything other than the two IDs.  If not, than use the HABTM, as it will do the join logic for you automatically (except creating the join table in the migration).  If you do HMT, then you will be defining the third model as an active record model, and you can name it anything you want.

Comment: Why it's many to many? How do `items` have many `orders`? Normally orders would have many items and each item would have a product.

Comment: @HalilÖzgür I was thinking many orders have many items and items belong to many orders. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Emma in a normal e-commerce app, order items should belong to a single order, i.e. an item (a product with a quantity) can't exist in multiple orders. Even if a product is ordered in the exact same quantity in multiple orders, each one would be a different item. Otherwise if an item is canceled from an order, it would be canceled from another person's order too inadvertently. An example e-commerce db schema: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/b2c.htm

Comment: @HalilÖzgür In the db schema example you provided, isn't `Order_Items` a HMT association joining `Orders` and `Products`?

Comment: @Emma here is a bare bones Rails implementation: https://gist.github.com/halilim/53aa2402fb2321f3ab27 You can look at [Spree's source code](https://github.com/spree/spree) for a much more advanced example, and [Magento's database diagram](http://www.magereverse.com/) if you want to see more than you'd ever hope.

Comment: @HalilÖzgür Great examples! From the bare bones implementation, it looks like the `Order_Items` as HMT is correct?

Comment: @Emma Firstly, I assume you mean "has many through" by HMT, right? If so, products have many orders through order items and orders have many products through order items. You can indirectly relate products and orders to each other through order items. Having said that, if we are to continue with the gist, exactly which part did you find confusing?

Comment: @HalilÖzgür I was confused because your comment above says: `Why it's many to many? How do items have many orders? Normally orders would have many items and each item would have a product.` But the gist you created shows that items(products) and orders have a many to many association.

Comment: @Emma well, I thought you meant it's possible that `OrderItem` can have a `has_many` or a `has_and_belongs_to_many` to `Order`, which doesn't make sense normally. Sorry if I've taken it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to know anything else about the relationship of the item on a particular order, you *need* HMT.

If your items change price in the future, do you want to know how much they were sold for on orders in the past?

In this type of requirement, I've always had many "LineItem" records for an order, and the line_item instances belong_to to the item and order, and record the pricing and/or quantity for that order.

HMT vs HABTM? There are so few times that *all* you need is a many-to-many, that I'd almost always go with HMT for the extra ability to add more information to the association.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a classic case of HABTM, and the [example given in the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) is perfect.  The choice comes down to whether you need any other data or logic on the join model itself.  If so, then use the HMT, where you will create a third active_record model to serve as the join table.  You can name that anything you want.  But it seems like HABTM will work for you, and all you need to setup is the join table with the default name (`items_orders`) in your migration, and rails will take care of everything else for you.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
end
```